# It's possible to add in windows an account of other domain? Appfabric cache configuration

Tags: caching, appfabric

We are having troubles with appfabric cache, if we do not use security, it works fine, if we use security, we need to add in the server an account from another domain and grant access to it in appfabric cache. How could we add an account from another domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not work, but where I've had a need to do this sort of thing before, it's been possible to create an account on each domain with the same name. When the call crosses the boundary from the first domain to the second, the identity loses its' domain information, but on the second domain the account matching the identity's name is used to continue the call.